# Modular Exponentiation with binary representation of exponent

Tags: c++, modular, exponentiation

Okay so I have an assignment to compute the binary representation of an integer and then reverse it into right to left notation and place that into a vector and perform modular exponentiation on it. I have the binary representation down, but I get the wrong answer when it comes down to the modular exponentiation portion. It may be something stupid I missed in the code but I've looked at examples and can't seem to figure out what the problem may be. Here is the code for the modular exponentiation here.

```
int ModularExpo(int a, vector<int> K, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    int b = 1;
    int A = a;
    if (K[0] == 1) {
        b = a;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < K.size() - 1; i++) {
        A = A * A % n;
        if (K[i] == 1) {
            b = A * b % n;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

So basically I send in the base (a), the exponent in binary form as a vector reversed (K) and the modulus (n). Initialize 2 variables b and A then check the first index to see if the K is even or odd, then go into my loop summing up everything. Still can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I actually figured it out. I wasn't looping all the way through the vector because I was using

```
i < K.size() - 1
```

when I should have used either

```
i < K.size()
```

or

```
i <= K.size() - 1
```

in my for loop.

Comment: go with `i < K.size()` less behind-the-scenes math, assuming the compiler doesn't recognize the `-1` and `<=` and strip it back down to `i < K.size()`.